# How do I redirect using '?' as part of my conditions

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http-redirect

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
/subdomain/?q=Keyword+Search -> /?q=Keyword+Search
/subdomain?q=Keyword+Search -> /?q=Keyword+Search
/subdomain/view.php?id=1 -> /subdomain/view.php?id=1
```

This is how I'm trying to do it (results in comments)

```
#/subdomain/?q=Keyword+Search -> /?q=Keyword+Search
RewriteRule ^subdomain/(.*) /$1 [R=301,L]    #redirects /subdomain/view.php to /view.php
RewriteRule ^subdomain/?(.*) /?$1 [R=301,L]  #redirects /subdomain/* to /
RewriteRule ^subdomain/ / [R=301,L]          #redirects /subdomain/* to /
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The question mark itself and all the query string are _not_ part of the URI, therefore you cannot match them in a `RewriteRule`. You have to use `RewriteCond`tions instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this rule with negative lookahead:

```
RewriteRule ^subdomain/((?!view\.php).*)$ /$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

Or else using a `RewriteCond`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdomain/(view|edit|reports|stats)\.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^subdomain/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: Thank you! How do I make that work with multiple lookaheads (IE: edit.php, reports.php, stats.php, etc.)? I'm guessing that could get pretty messy if I start adding very many.

Comment: It will be a few hours before I can try it again. Thank you. I'll let you know.